# jQuery show array from PHP (json encoded)

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to show an array with jQuery, but it doesn't show anything i want :P

So im asking here after been sitting on google and here for the nearest hour and still can't figure out what im doing wrong..

My array is this:

```
if (isset($_POST['imageID'])) { 
            $array = array();
            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("../img/libary/".$_POST['imageID'].".JPG");

            $array["dimension"] = $width.' x '.$height;
            $array["filesize"] = formatBytes(filesize("../img/libary/".$_POST['imageID'].".jpg"),0);
            $array["extensions"] = strtoupper(pathinfo("../img/libary/".$_POST['imageID'].".jpg", PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $array["filename"] = $_database->query("SELECT * FROM imglibary WHERE imageID='".$_POST['imageID']."' LIMIT 1")->fetch_object()->name; 
            $array["fileurl"] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/libary/'.$_POST['imageID'].'.JPG';

            echo json_encode($array);
        }
```

And jQuery code:

```
$.post("jQuery.post.php", {imageID: imageID}, "json").done(function(data) { 
 // What to do here to get it to work? 
  });
```

Hope you guys have an answer im all out of them :(

Missed to show the answer from "data":

```
{"dimension": "210x214", "filesize", "214kb", "extensions", "JPG", "filename": "somefile.jpg", "fileurl": "/img/libary/40.JPG"}
```

Comment: As aldrin said, you want to parse the data. [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Comment: I thought when you stated JSON as the data type it parses the data automatically?

Comment: @PaparazzoKid not if it's being sent as `text/html` from the php.

Comment: @Darren - thanks, that makes sense. But, how did you know that the OP's PHP header was set to `text/html` and not `application/json`?

Comment: @PaparazzoKid It would've parsed otherwise ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.parseJSON` to parse the data returned from the server, unless you're sending an `application/json` header from your PHP page.

If you want to start sending the correct JSON headers from your PHP pages, add this to the top of your pages, by default it's set to `text/html`, which is why your data needs to be parsed:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Then, it's as simple as `console.log(data.dimension)` without any need of parsing. As long as you set `json` as the `dataType`, jQuery will automatically parse the data for you.

If you don't want to/can't send the correct headers or you're unsure what they are, then use `parseJSON()`.

**Example with parseJSON:**

```
$.post("jQuery.post.php", {imageID: imageID}, "json").done(function(data) { 
   var d = $.parseJSON(data);
   console.log(d.dimension);
});
```

Comment: I only get undefined when i do that.